Replicación solo del esquema - SQL Server
Necesito configurar una publicación donde solo se replique la estructura de ciertas tablas (sin datos) entre dos instancias SQL Server.
He estado investigando y en algunos sitios veo que esto es viable si se modifica el criterio Copy Data pero no lo encuentro en la instancia que estoy trabajando (SQL Server 2017) o no se si estoy buscando el parámetro incorrecto.
¿Podrían asesorarme al respecto, por favor?
